# Delphi dont know about LoadTypeLib?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, typelib

i have a Delphi7.

I use this article: http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=2 / Step 2

Now, i created a problem with LoadTypeLib (undefined):

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TAutoIntfObject, IMyIntf, IDispatch)
    constructor Create();
  protected
    procedure helloWorld(); safecall;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyClass.Create();
var
  TypeLib: ITypeLib;
  s: WideString;
begin
  s := ParamStr(0);
  OleCheck(LoadTypeLib(PWideChar(s), TypeLib)); // ERR:LoadTypeLib is undefined.
  inherited Create(TypeLib, IMyCallback); 
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Delphi 7, the `LoadTypeLib` function is declared in the `ActiveX` unit. You must include that unit in your uses clause.

You can find this stuff out for yourself the exact same way that I did it – by searching the source code. Use the *Find in Files* feature, search for the name of the symbol that is not declared, and search under the `Source` directory of your Delphi installation.